# My requirement is that I have to create DLRS for 'the date when the most recent email was received'

Tags: salesforce

My requirement is that I have to create DLRS for 'the date when the most recent email was received' How can I create DLRS with the help of apex class for 'the date when the most recent email was received'.

I want to create the DLRS for 'the date when the most recent email was received'.
How can I create the DLRS for these conditions for getting the date of received mail by using the apex class?